# Changing table rows depending on 3 selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Depending on the value selected with the 3 selectors I only have to display the rows that contain those values selected earlier at the same time.

I currently have this and it works for one selector. How can I extend it for all the 3 selectors to affect the rows displayed?

```
    <select id="selA">
      <option value="0">Toate</option>
      <option value="a1">A1</option>
      <option value="a2">A2</option>
      <option value="a3">A3</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="selB">
      <option value="0">Toate</option>
      <option value="b1">B1</option>
      <option value="b2">B2</option>
      <option value="b3">B3</option>
      <option value="b4">B4</option>
      <option value="b5">B5</option>
      <option value="b6">B6</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="selC">
      <option value="0">Toate</option>
      <option value="c1">C1</option>
      <option value="c2">C2</option>
      <option value="c3">C3</option>
      <option value="c4">C4</option>
      <option value="c5">C5</option>
      <option value="c6">C6</option>
      <option value="c7">C7</option>
      <option value="c8">C8</option>
      <option value="c9">C9</option>
      <option value="c10">C10</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="choice one">A1</td>
        <td class="choice one">B1</td>
        <td class="choice one">C1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="choice one">A1</td>
        <td class="choice one">B1</td>
        <td class="choice one">C2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="choice one">A1</td>
        <td class="choice one">B1</td>
        <td class="choice one">C3</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="choice one">A1</td>
        <td class="choice one">B2</td>
        <td class="choice one">C4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

AND JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selA").change(function(){
    var textselected =  document.getElementById("selA").value ;
    target = '.' + textselected;
    $('.choice').hide();
    $(target).show();

  });
});
```

How can I make it so it doesn't depend on the class and hides the rows that don't have ALL the values in the selectors?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't seem to be working - https://jsfiddle.net/agkh7f3w/ ... if 'a1' is selected, then your jQuery target = '.a1', but there is no element in your html that has an 'a1' class ... Do you want your code to analyze the td contents or are your tr's supposed to contain a#, b# and c# classes?

Comment: @Kory I want it to analyze the content of TD-TR (innerHTML) but I copied a wrong version here.

Comment: Will you post the right code then? --- StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Display only the rows that contain the values selected using the selectors

Comment: I got it... But post your attempt. The JS code you posted is nothing about that. SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, I think you want something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/agkh7f3w/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="filtru">filtru:
  <select id="selA">
    <option value="">Toate</option>
    <option value="a1">A1</option>
    <option value="a2">A2</option>
    <option value="a3">A3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="selB">
    <option value="">Toate</option>
    <option value="b1">B1</option>
    <option value="b2">B2</option>
    <option value="b3">B3</option>
    <option value="b4">B4</option>
    <option value="b5">B5</option>
    <option value="b6">B6</option>
  </select>
  <select id="selC">
    <option value="">Toate</option>
    <option value="c1">C1</option>
    <option value="c2">C2</option>
    <option value="c3">C3</option>
    <option value="c4">C4</option>
    <option value="c5">C5</option>
    <option value="c6">C6</option>
    <option value="c7">C7</option>
    <option value="c8">C8</option>
    <option value="c9">C9</option>
    <option value="c10">C10</option>
  </select>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>C4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filtru select').change(function() {
    const filtru = [$('#selA').val(), $('#selB').val(), $('#selC').val()];
    $('#table tr').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
      $('td', this).each(function(i) {
        const text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (text.indexOf(filtru[i]) === -1) {
          $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        }
      })
    })
  });
});
```